# C# WPF create dynamic textbox for each row of ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, dynamic, textbox

I would like to know, how to create dynamic textboxes for each row of a ListView. I'm using a MVVM for my WPF Application. If you have any Questions, then please ask me.

Let's say this is my ListView:

[image]

And i would like to have a ListView and TextBoxes like this:

[image]

The Cells right to the ListView are my TextBoxes. Now my problem is: I want to create dynamiclly two TextBoxes for each row of my ListView. I'm new with WPF and i really would to know, how to create dynamic TextBoxes with the range of the rows in a ListView.

I hope for help, grettings Nankatzu.

Comment: What content should be in the TextBoxes?

Comment: How dose you data model look like? Do you have classes with properties or dynamic data?

Comment: Just a String, i want to use both TextBoxes for a String. Later i need this String to do a Compare. But what you just have to know is, that i will use the TextBoxes as String. I'm using Classes with Properties.

Comment: why can't the textboxes be part of the `ListView`? Meaning like two additional columns?

Comment: Because i'm loading more than one table. That means, my ListView can have 3 rows or 4 rows or 5 rows. Thats why i need dynamic TextBoxes. The Programm should know the range of my rows and add to each row two TextBoxes.

Comment: Why are you not using DataGrid for this?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can help. This must be for VB.Net part. Maybe you can change it to C#

```
For x = 0 To 4
    Dim GridView1 As New GridViewColumn()

     Dim datatemple1 As New DataTemplate()
     Dim Textbox1 = New FrameworkElementFactory(GetType(TextBox))
     datatemple1.VisualTree = Textbox1

     GridView1.Header = "Employee No." & x
     GridView1.Width = 100
     GridView1.CellTemplate = datatemple1

     UGridview1.Columns.Add(GridView1)
     ListView1.Items.Add(datatemple1)

 Next
 ListView1.View = UGridview1
```

XAML part must like this:

```
<ListView x:Name="ListView1">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView x:Name="UGridview1" >
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```